# Is the legacy firebase API still supported?

Tags: firebase

I have been developing a firebase app for a few months now. Looks like the API is changing with the Google migration. Can i still use the old version of Firebase (2.3.2). We are getting ready to QA no way can we just change our code like this.

Comment: Not sure why this is a "-1"

Comment: This is a really good question and the answer should be stated somewhere in Firebase docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Firebaser here*

The Firebase 2.x SDKs will keep working. We have no current plans to retire the 2.x API, just as we've kept our 1.x APIs up since we introduced 2.0 (in November 2014).

We of course hope that you'll find the new [features](https://firebase.google.com/features/) and [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) compelling enough to upgrade your project to our [new Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and at some point also update your code to the new SDKs. We have handy migration guides for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios) and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) apps.